# calling ng2-dragula ondrop event not working

Tags: typescript, angular, dragula

I am dragging and dropping one component on the following [row-bag].component is getting drag-dropped successfully.

```
<li *ngFor="#secRowColumn of sectionRow.secRowColumns;#secRowColumnIndex=index" 
    [dragula]='"row-bag"' (ondrop)="print(secRowColumnIndex)" 
    class="col-md-{{12/sectionRow.secRowColumns.length}}"
    style="margin:0 auto;border:1px solid gray;"       
    [ngClass]="secRowColumn.cssClass" 
    >
        <generic-component component-name="{{secRowColumn.colName}}" [(component-model)]="secRowColumn.model"></generic-component>
</li>
```

the *ngFor loop renders columns on page and I am trying to drop components in one of these columns, what I want is when I drop a component in 2nd column I want to access its index i.e. `secRowColumnIndex`.

I tried event binding as `(ondrop)="print(secRowColumnIndex)"` but could not get any success.
also I tried printing args of ondrop method as follow:

```
dragulaService.drop.subscribe((value: any[]) => {
        console.log(`drop: ${value[0]}`);
        this.onDrop(value.slice(1));
        console.log(value);//secRowColumnIndex is not received here too.
    });
```

doing above does not print the `secRowColumnIndex`.any inputs about how can I access `secRowColumnIndex`?